# Is using a capacitor to transfer a 0.1 V differential between voltage levels reasonable?

Tags: voltage, capacitor, differential

The temperature of a terminal at -600 V and 500°C needs to be measured. I am using a thermocouple for this, and to achieve the most accurate reading the couple must be physically connected to the -600 V terminal.

The two leads on the thermocouple will be at approximately -600.0 V and -600.1 V (for example). How can I transfer this voltage difference to ground so I may measure it with an ADC?

The way I am considering at the moment is to charge a capacitor with the small current from the thermocouple (sample rate can be in the range of tens of seconds). Then, using relays, disconnect the capacitor from the thermocouple and using a second relay to connect it to my ADC at ground level.

[image]

I thought about this since it is similar to how bootstrap capacitors are used to drive high-side loads - charging a cap with low voltage, and then connecting it to the high rail in order to charge a MOSFET gate.

Is this reasonable? Or are there other, more traditional ways to do this?

Comment: I'd probably go with something like an "isolated amplifier" with an isolated DC-DC to float a 5V power supply on your high voltage terminal.

Comment: Capacitors have leakage and a temperature coefficient. You probably can make it work with a bit of calibration, but what accuracy do you need? Traditional approach would be to float the ADC and opto isolated the digital signal back to the host.

Comment: Would it be possible to use a thermally conductive but electrically insulating epoxy to connect the thermocouple?

Comment: @ElliotAlderson. Good idea, but some thermal epoxies are very corrosive to metals and skin. Also need a 500 C rating.

Comment: @A.S. I would look into Tom Carpenters suggestion of a isolation amp. Analog Devices makes a AD210KN that is powered by an isolated 15 volts DC, with 1,500 volts isolation and a 500 KHZ sample rate. It is something I did often with great accuracy.

Comment: There are integrated temperature sensors with built in ADC and serial interface. Use a optocoupler to brudge the serial interface to a different voltage level.

Comment: If one relay gets stuck it will fry the circuitry

Comment: Why not use an IR sensor or purchase an instrument to do this. I have one and it is quite accurate and it is safe. If it is a continuous measurement they make instruments that would do what you want.